# what's your utf-8 console setting when programming Google Go under Windows

Tags: go, windows-console

We know google's Go default is UTF-8.
I found in my Windows XP. It can not display correct about the UTF-8.
The following code display in wrong.

```
package main

func main() {
  println("中文")
}
```

I've googled. It said use another font + reg + chcp 65001.
But, I failed.

I've tried cmd and powershell v1 (it is the only provide version under XP).
Both can NOT display well.

Comment: I think that the problem isn't with the code page (65001) but only in the font. Using Lucida Console I'm able to print UTF-8 like "абвгдеж эюя" on the Windows console, but not you characters. Chinese glyphs are probably not available in the Lucida Console font so I guess you'll have to find another font (and make the Windows Command Processor use it). Why MS doesn't think it's important to have the Chinese, Japanese and Korean glyphs available is another question...

Comment: @dystroy Sounds pretty lame: Unix consoles use a font-substitution policy just like a web browser, falling back to alternate fixed-width fonts for missing glyphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Install MSYS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst)
- Download [mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) and put mintty.exe in   c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
- Adjust *MinGW Shell* icon, set target as C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat **-mintty**, then click the icon
- Menu->Option->Text->Font, Locale,Character set(UTF-8)
- Download [go Windows 386](http://code.google.com/p/go/downloads/list)
- cd /c/go/src ; mkdir  ; test your code here.
- BTW, setting [vim with utf-8](http://www.liuhuadong.com/archives/68/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I will try this the next time I'm at a Windows XP machine.  I develop mostly on Win 7 and CentOS.  One thought, cmd.exe is awfully old on Windows XP.  I wonder if it would work better if run from PowerShell.  Also, in the last couple days I've switched to using [MSys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) on Windows so that I can take advantage of unified makefiles on Linux and Windows.  I'll post an update if I get the command to work on XP or 7.

Comment: I’ve heard that none of the terminal programs from Microsoft handle UTF-8 correctly, that you have to use a third-party application to get good UTF-8 support.

Comment: Well, I seem to be having problems just getting the text into an editor.  I looks funny in TextPad, Notepad, and Notepad++.  I did get it to compile, but "go install test.go" won't even properly compile it.  It outputs an executable but doesn't give it a ".exe" extension like you normally would get.  When I ran it (after changing the extension), I got strange output from the program.  The characters did not look the same.  Sadly I'm pretty ignorant when it comes to foreign encodings.

Comment: Just tried it out on my Mac with zero issues.  Bummer, Windows seems to just be all kinds of pain with these sorts of characters.

Comment: That’s because a Mac handles UTF-8 well, including using terminal programs with font substitution policies so that no one font has to cover all code points.  Apparently Microsoft hasn’t figured this out yet.